# ajax .show() doesn't reveal hidden div on signup?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im trying to have a success alert or error alert div appear and return a json message when a new user signs up (via form). I can see the json output in the console (i.e the messages populates in console) but I don't see the div nor the object as text appear on the html page.

**Below is what I have:**

**Html:**

```
<script src="../static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/signUp.js"></script>
<div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;" ></div>
```

**Signup js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSignUp").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/signUp",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                $("#successAlert").html("response").show();

            },
            error: function(error){
                $("#errorAlert").html("error").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Signup py:**

```
@app.route("/signUp",methods=["POST", "GET"])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form["inputName"]
        _email = request.form["inputEmail"]
        _password = request.form["inputPassword"]

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.callproc("sp_createUser",(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
                conn.commit()
                return jsonify({"message":"User created successfully !"})
            else:
                return jsonify({"error":str(data[0])})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error":str(e)})

    finally:
           cursor.close()
           conn.close()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$("#successAlert").html("response").show();` here you are appending a string to dom instead manipulate your response object. If it is json parse it as a json object.

Comment: try with $("#successAlert").show().html("response")

Comment: @SumeshTG, Doesn't the use of jsonify already do this (i.e. "parse it as a json object")?

Comment: @user713789, I have tried that (thank you). It doesn't work though. the hidden div still does not show up even when console returns success message.

Comment: @eRyan please check the status code in dev tool, is it 200 for OK and are correctly coming in response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing everything in the `#successAlert` with `.html()` use `.append()` and add the `dataType:'json'` to the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/signUp",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    dataType:'json', // <------add this to parse the response as json
    success: function(response){
        $("#successAlert").append(response.message).show();// put message then show.

    },
    error: function(error){
        $("#errorAlert").append(error.error).show();// put error then show.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSignUp").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/signUp",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                $("#successAlert").html("response").show();

            },
            error: function(error){
                $("#errorAlert").html("error").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;" ></div>
<input type="submit" id="btnSignUp">
```

The error div is working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which of these is the fix, but I think I fixed my issue by adding type="text/javascript" to my js script imports on the html page. Also, when running the webapp locally my css and js files do not update unless I change the name of the file (which is very strange). I will open a new question for this issue.

HTML was adjusted to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/signUp.js"></script>
```

Thank you for the help!